# How to establish existence of an optimal control with infinite horizon?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, improper-integrals, control-theory

If I have a quadratic cost functional such as \begin{equation} J(x_0, \ u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \bigg(x^TQx +  u^TRu \bigg)\ dt  \end{equation} $Q, R$ are positive-definite, and the dynamics $\dot{x} = f(x)+g(x)u$, $x(0) = x_0$ are such that $g(0) = 0$, and also that $f$ is not dissipative with respect to any positive definite storage function, for example $f = Ax$ with $A$ having only imaginary eigenvalues, so that trajectories may decay very slowly around the origin, how can I prove or disprove that the minimum cost functional is actually finite?

My first try with this was knowing that state components that decay at a rate of $\frac{1}{x^p}$ where $p>.5$ would lead to a finite $J$, but I'm not sure how to bound solutions to ODEs I don't know the solution to, much less ones that aren't fully determined (the $u$ part).

Any advice toward how to begin solving a problem like this would be appreciated. I'm also aware that the optimum may not exist in the sense that one can always find a smaller number by perturbing the control by a vanishingly small amount - something like the concept of an open set in the space of controllers - this information would be welcome although isn't my primary aim as I intend to address the problem of finding the "practically optimal" control via numerical methods.

Comment: Any condition on $f$?

Comment: Hi KBS, f is lossless. To be clearer, I'm looking at generalizations of a system with variable stiffness: mq'' + (k+u)q = 0. This leads to $ f = [x2, \ -\frac{k}{m}x1]^T$. The uncontrolled dynamics oscillate forever. Control is only added as a multiplier of some part of the state

Comment: Alright, in that case could you please update your question with all the details. In such problems, all the details matter and may need to be fully exploited. Also, make sure to provide a definition for "lossless" for completeness.

Comment: To be honest, the trouble is in deciding whether to ask a general question or a specific one. I think this one got caught in the middle, thanks for the feedback. Will be updating soon.

Comment: I have updated the question to hopefully be better